# why compilers dont support c++11 thread_local storage?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11, thread-local

AFAIK both g++ and cl both support compiler specific TL storage... so Im wondering is C++11 TLS  different from what they support now?

> Thread Local Storage (TLS) is the method by which each thread in a
>   given multithreaded process can allocate locations in which to store
>   thread-specific data. Dynamically bound (run-time) thread-specific
>   data is supported by way of the TLS API ([TlsAlloc], [TlsGetValue],
>   [TlsSetValue], and [TlsFree]). Win32 and the Visual C++ compiler now
>   support statically bound (load-time) per-thread data in addition to
>   the existing API implementation.

Also for VS **11** support is listed as partial.
For g++ it is not even in GCC4.7

Comment: Well, *"partial"* support in MS terms means, *"we have a similar feature, just that it's not the C++11 feature, but uses totally different syntax and results in the same platform-dependent code you could already write years before C++11"*, and thus simply translates to *"no"*.

Comment: Given that only GCC 4.8 supports this feature as of April 2013, it may not be very easy. In fact, only GCC 4.8 supports the construction and destruction semantics of `thread_local`. If you want define a C++ object (that has constructor or destructor) with `__thread` in GCC 4.7 (or earlier) or `__declspec(thread)` in MSVC, the compiler will complain. Clang compiles my object marked with `__thread` well, but it does not create the object for each new thread.

Answer (score 3):

With g++, its pretty close, at least for ELF-based systems.  Just compile with
 `-Dthread_local=__thread` and you get most of it -- the only issue is contructors and destructors not being called, but as long as you use POD-types for your thread-local variables that's not an issue.

Comment: tnx for the info, but const/dest thing makes it almost useless for nontrivial data. But still nice to know that. Tnx a lot!

Comment: You can get around the ctor/dtor issue by making the thread-local var a pointer and point it at a local var in the top-level thread main function.

Answer (score 1):

The standard was published only a month ago. I am sure many design meetings etc are going on before they begin on such a huge task. By the way most c++ compilers dont completely support the C++98 version of the standard - so be patient.

Comment: Most compilers never will support C++98, simply because of exported templates. It's not that they haven't got around to it, it's that it was a mistake to include in the standard because, and the only vendor to ever implement it (EDG) requested its removal in C++11. Because of this clang and g++ will probably have full C++11 support full before C++98 support.